# value of input not posted

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function() {

    $("#distributor").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Devices/autoDistributor", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                    data: { name: request.term, maxResults: 10 },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data, function(item) {
                            return { value: item.Name }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
            //alert(ui.item.value);

            }
        });


    });
</script>

   <% using (Html.BeginForm("Filtering","Devices",FormMethod.Post)) {%>


   Distributor: <input id="distributor" type="text"/>

   <input id="finish_button" type="submit" value="Search"  />


  <% } %>
```

When i post form, text who is inserted in input (id="distributor") is not posted, why???

Comment: Is this happening when you press enter for the autocomplete? Is it possible the default form submit is firing before the box has a chance to populate the value in that case?

Comment: form is submiting when I press on Search button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<input>` is missing the `name` attribute, like this:

```
<input id="distributor" name="distributor" type="text"/>
```

Without this, it doesn't get serialized/submitted when the `<form>` does :)